# Hiding zero values in Excel chart or diagram, legend and labeling

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-charts

As you can see in the attached image, my diagram accesses the table on the left. Though the values are changing and it appears that sometimes a value is 0. In this case the entire row of the table neither should be shown in the diagram nor in the legend or labeling.

How can I implement such a diagram? [Example: Table with diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVQm6.jpg) (In the example, the gas costs should not be displayed)

Answer (score 18):

1. Right click at one of the data labels, and select **Format Data Labels**
   from the context menu
2. In the Format Data Labels dialog, Click **Number** in left pane, then **select Custom** from the Category list box, and type `#""` into the Format Code text box, and click Add button to add it to Type list box.
3. Click **Close** button to close the dialog. Then you can see all zero data labels are hidden.